# Use OCR function of google docs on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-drive-api

How can i use this on the google apps script? i want to upload attachments from gmail. Also, i want to use the ocr function of google docs since all of the attatchments will be images.

```
function uploadFile() {
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://goo.gl/nd7zjB').getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: 'google_logo.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your file varaible to Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true});

Please note, OCR didn't work for me when I used the image you supplied. Test it out with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i90M.png) and should work fine for you.

```
function uploadFile() {
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i90M.png').getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: 'imagehastext.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true});
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
}
```

Here's a rough example of how to get an email attachment.

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getAttachments();
```

[And some documentation on how to save files to Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

Comment: how can i add this on my application? i got the code from the google apps script site and i want to implement it on my own application. Im making a scrpt that saves attachments from google drive and use ocr on it.

Comment: should i get the attachment as  a blob?