# Google Spreadsheet: Parsing .PDF from Google Drive

Tags: parsing, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm still getting into google spreadsheets, recently understood how to format a `.txt` to be able to use `=ImportData` properly thanks to Tanaike's assitance, now tackling a -slightly- more challenging task.

**Goal:**

Automatically extracting specific data from .pdf files hosted inside of a google drive folder and arranging the information into specific cells

**Challenges:**

- Being able to decode the blobs of information, as [just the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww3kY.png) obtained with `=ImportData` is useless
- Truly learning how to use `google-apps-script` for something useful (that's on my own)
- Instructing a single extraction of information rather than constant online status as with `=ImportData`
- [Second Priority] Stop Depending on an add-on (`Drive Direct Links`) to get the URL of the files

To my understanding, I'll need to do some parsing. I know `.pdf` is not always straight forward, all the files will come from the same place and have the exact same format, so understanding how to do it once should be enough.
I already know how to get the real/permanent link to the files automatically and how to arrange information segregated into cells using `=Index`, `=Extract` and others.

Hope I'm being clear enough. Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards,

Lucas.-

Comment: Although I'm not sure about ``specific data``, if you want to retrieve string text from PDF, for example, how about retrieving them by converting PDF to text data using OCR? About OCR, you can use Drive API of Google and APIs of other site. If you want to retrieve the metadata of PDF, a simple data can be retrieved by Drive API. But if you want to retrieve the detail, you are required to use APIs of other site or a direct parsing. For all methods, Google Apps Script is required to be used. If these are not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Yes, I want to retrieve `specific data` from the `.PDF` files. Unfortunately, the data changes, so I can't just use OCR to look up for a specific (as in quote and quote string) piece of text. I need to retrieve a field from a table inside the `.PDF`
Any suggestion on how to tackle this? I'm reading into drive API for the time being, a pointer would be very welcomed.

Comment: I just did some trials.

If I download the `.PDF` from google drive as `.TXT` and upload them into google drive again, I can use `=Importdata` to get the information I need in a similar fashion to what I did with other `.TXT` recently (separating into cells and whatnot). That would work, but I need to do it automatically from the `.PDF` in order to cut down time and workload. I still need to get the script working.

Comment: You want to retrieve values from PDF file without using OCR. But you want to retrieve text file from PDF file. If my understanding is correct, you are required to directly parse PDF file. I'm not sure about the method.

Comment: But if you use OCR, you can achieve it using Files: create of Drive API. The document is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). The related thread are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406966/upload-pdf-with-ocr-with-google-apps-script-and-possibly-drive-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431795/use-ocr-function-of-google-docs-on-google-apps-script).